# R: Remove intervals by criteria with overlap tolerance

Tags: r

I am searching for a solution to create some mask, with which I can remove some data (e.g. rows in data.frame) depending on some criteria, e.g.:

```
a <- c(0,0,0,3,5,6,3,0,0,0,4,5,8,5,0,0,0,0,0)
mask <- a == 0
mask
[1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE TRUE TRUE
```

In my actual problem this cut is too harsh, I would like to have some smoother transition. The idea: I want to include some zeros before the non-zeros, and also add some zeros after the non-zeros. Simple approach: if I have this vector, I would like to switch every TRUE adjacent to a FALSE into a FALSE, which adds a overlapping tolerance region to the data. So instead of

```
a[!mask]
[1] 3 5 6 3 4 5 8 5
```

I would rather have something like

```
a[!mask]
[1] 0 3 5 6 3 0 0 4 5 8 5 0
```

or (increasing the size of the tolerance window)

```
a[!mask]
[1] 0 0 3 5 6 3 0 0 0 4 5 8 5 0 0
```

In the last case the three zeros in the middle arise, since the tolerance from the left and from the right start overlapping. My question: has anyone a good approach, how to write a function to create such a mask with overlapping tolerance?

**[EDIT]** It to me some time I realised the error in my initial question (thanks @tospig) In my initial post I completely made the number of zeros in the middle part wrong! Sorry for the confusion. So, for clarification: in the case of a tolerance window of 1, there really should be two zeros in the middle: one from the right bunch of valid data, one from the left bunch of valid data. Sorry for the confusion!

So, despite the really cool approach from @tospig (which I have to keep in mind) the solution from @agenis solves my problem perfectly!

Comment: The increasing the tolerance part is not clear.  Suppose you are adding 3 zeros, will it be 4 zeros between the non-zero numbers

Comment: No, the maximum numbers of zeros (as in data) should remain. In the initial example there are three zeros, so independent of the tolerance, there should always be this maximum number of three zeros.

Comment: Then, why is in the first case, there is only one zero?  Anyway, my solution gives the first case.

Comment: @akrun - I think that's the purpose of the 'tolerance' - use a variable to set how many `0`s are allowed, so in the first case the tolerance will be `1`.

Comment: I've added a solution that allows you to specify your `tolerance`, and it preserves the correct / max number of consecutive zeros

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I would go with a classic moving average of order 3 which simply expands the "non-zeros" by one to the left and one to the right. As simple as this. You will just have to figure out what you do with the first and the last point of your vector that are turned into NA (in my example I make them zeros).

And you have your desired result (for a bigger mask you take the order 5 instead of 3):

```
a <- c(0,0,0,3,5,6,3,0,0,0,4,5,8,5,0,0,0,0,0)
library(forecast)
a.ma <- ma(a, 3)
a.ma[is.na(a.ma)] <- 0
mask <- a.ma == 0
a[!mask]
#### [1] 0 3 5 6 3 0 0 4 5 8 5 0
```

Then you can easily transform this piece of code into a function.

**[EDIT]** this method does not ensure the conservation of the total number of zeros (see additional comments to clarify the OP initial question)

Comment: This gives 2 zeros in the middle

Comment: Elegant solution despite the little flaw mentioned by @akrun.

Comment: @PJussel - is this actually a flaw, given the last point in your question about having three zeros rather than two, because they overlap?

Comment: @tospig true, thanks for this hint. This is not a flaw, but even highlighted the error in my initial question.

Comment: @PJussel glad you/we finally got it sorted :)

Answer (score 2):

We can try

```
library(data.table)
lst1 <- split(a[!mask],rleid(mask)[!mask])

c(0,unlist(Map(`c`, lst1, 0), use.names=FALSE))
#[1] 0 3 5 6 3 0 4 5 8 5 0
```

---

Or another option is

```
n <- 1
i1 <- !inverse.rle(within.list(rle(mask), {
          lengths[values] <- lengths[values]-n
          lengths[!values] <- lengths[!values]+n}))
c(a[i1],0)
#[1] 0 3 5 6 3 0 4 5 8 5 0
```

Comment: I may have misinterpreted the OP's question, howver, your second solution fails for `n <- 4` (or when `n` is greater than the minimum number of consecutive zeros).

Comment: I have to better understand the concept of your first solution, this one looks promising. But I think counting of zeros (initial, in the middle and in the end) is necessary to get it fully working for me...

Comment: @tospig I think all the solutions posted here have some kind of issues that doesn't fully meet with the OP's concept.  If this is a big issue, I can delete it.

Comment: @akrun despite that, I think it's the best one and is closest to (my understanding of) the original question.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution that allows you to specify the tolerance. At the moment it doesn't 'overlap' zeros.

We can use a `data.table` structure (or a `data.frame`, but I like using `data.table`) and control how many zeros we want to keep between the set of positive numbers. We can specify any `tolerance` value, but if it's greater than a sequence of zeros, only the maximum number of consecutive zeroes will be returned.

```
a <- c(0,0,0,3,5,6,3,0,0,0,4,5,8,5,0,0,0,0,0)

library(data.table)
tolerance <- 1

dt <- data.table( id = seq(1, length(a), by = 1),
                  a = a)

## subset all the 0s, with their 'ids' for joining back on 
dt_zero <- dt[a == 0]

## get the positions where the difference between values is greater than one, 
## and create groups based on their length
changed <- which(c(TRUE, diff(dt_zero$id) > 1))
dt_zero$grps <- rep(changed, diff(c(changed, nrow(dt_zero) + 1)))

## we only need the 'tolerance' number of zeros
## if 'tolerance' is greater than number of entries in a group,
## it will return 'na'
dt_zero <- dt_zero[  dt_zero[ order(id) , .I[c(1:tolerance)], by=grps ]$V1, ]

## join back onto original data.table, 
## and subset only relevant results
dt_zero <- dt_zero[, .(id, a)][ dt  , on = "id"][(is.na(a) & i.a > 0) | a == 0]

res <- dt_zero$i.a
res
# [1] 0 3 5 6 3 0 4 5 8 5 0

## try different tolerances
tolerance <- 2
...
# 0 0 3 5 6 3 0 0 4 5 8 5 0 0

tolerance <- 6
...
# 0 0 0 3 5 6 3 0 0 0 4 5 8 5 0 0 0 0 0
```